i want to export created_at in qatar time zone
my code for converting created_at in qatar time zone works in admin grid ,i need code for exporting createad at in qatar time, i have tried didn't get converted during export
public function __construct(
    TimezoneInterface $timezone,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
            if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                // Convert time to Qatar timezone
                $gmtTime = $item[$fieldName];
                $qatarTimeZone = 'Asia/Qatar';
                $qatarTime = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($gmtTime))
                    ->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($qatarTimeZone))
                    ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $item[$fieldName] = $qatarTime;

            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}

}

Please try this
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;

class QatarTime extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    protected $timezone;

    public function __construct(
        TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                    // Convert time to Qatar timezone
                    $gmtTime = $item[$fieldName];
                    $qatarTimeZone = 'Asia/Qatar';
                    $qatarTime = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($gmtTime))
                        ->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($qatarTimeZone))
                        ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $item[$fieldName] = $qatarTime;
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }

    public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();
        if ($this->getContext()->getRequestParam('namespace') == 'sales_order_grid') {
            $config = $this->getData('config');
            $config['label'] = __('Created At (Qatar Time)');
            $this->setData('config', $config);
        }
    }
}

<column name="created_at" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\QatarTime">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At (Qatar Time)</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>

